# Unity: GameObject always at center regardless of position changes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D game and have created a game object using C# script as below. I also set my camera to orthogonal and have adjusted my sprite based on the width of the screen. Regardless of the position I set, the object is always at the center of the screen. How can I solve this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestingPositions : MonoBehaviour {

 GameObject hero;
 Sprite heroSprite;
 Vector3 heroPosition;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

       hero = new GameObject ();
       Instantiate (hero, heroPosition, Quaternion.identity);
     Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();
     heroPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/4, Screen.height/4, camera.nearClipPlane));
     heroSprite = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Sprites/heroImage");
     SpriteRenderer renderer = hero.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();        renderer.sprite = heroSprite;
 }
}
```

Comment: You set `heroPosition` after you use it in `Instantiate` and you set it to be at `Screen.width/2` and `Screen.height/2`. That code is messy. Also, why don't you create a prefab for your charater instead of creating the whole gameobject from scratch?

Comment: How would I implement this the above position for my game object using a prefab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use **Instantiate** you have to use it on

## an existing model.

Instantiate means "duplicate this model" or "copy this model", or "make a new one, using this model as an example".

What you are doing, is creating a brand new empty "hero" game object - and then "instantiating" it.  That is meaningless and does nothing.

What you must do whenever you want to use "Instantiate" is this:

```
 public GameObject modelPerson;
```

Note that the name **must** be "modelSomething".

first put that in your code.  LOOK at the Inspector.  MAKE your actual model hero (or whatever it is)

Sit it somewhere off camera where it is not seen.

Now, **drag that thing** to the "modelPerson" slot in the Inspector.

If you are not familiar with the basics of using Inspector-dragging in Unity, review basic Unity tutorials https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting

Next in your code, perhaps in Start, try this

```
GameObject newHero = Instantiate( modelPerson );
newHero.transform.position = .. whatever you want
newHero.transform.rotation = .. whatever you want
newHero.name = "Dynamically created";
newHero.transform.parent = .. whatever you want
```

once you understand these basics, there is very much more to learn about Instantiate.  You can ask that in separate questions.  Good luck.

Comment: Beat me by 16 seconds :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Your need to save the reference to your gameObject that is created with Instantiate, [because Instantiate makes a copy not modifies the original](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).
2. To modify a gameobjects position after instantiation, you need to use gameobject.transform.position = newPosition; To modify it before instantiation, you would need to do the "heroPosition" line before using heroPosition in Instantiate.

So like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestingPositions : MonoBehaviour
{

GameObject hero;
SpriteRenderer heroSprite;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();

    //Save the reference to the instantiated object into a variable
    //Since you are creating an object from scratch, you don't even need Instantiate, which means copy - not create.
    hero = new GameObject();
    //Set its position
    hero.transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, camera.nearClipPlane));
    //Set its rotation
    hero.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    //Add sprite renderer, save the reference
    heroSprite = hero.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //Assign the sprite
    heroSprite.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/heroImage");
 }
}
```

Comment: you know what realistically the OP needs to learn about Instantiating a model .. it's impossible at this stage he would ever need to "build" a gameobject from scratch you know ...  Anyways...

Comment: He is working in 2D, what he already had is basically all he needs to "build" a gameobject, it just needed rearranged ;)